# convergence of $\int_a^b \frac{1}{x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is it true that $\int_0^a \frac{dx}{x^2} = \infty$ but $\int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2} < \infty$?

Shouldn't it be symmetric?

Comment: Have you worked the problems out? What's a?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By **definition**:

$$\begin{align}&\int_0^a\frac{dx}{x^2}=\left.\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\left(-\frac1x\right)\right|^a_\epsilon=-\frac1a+\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac1\epsilon=\infty\\{}\\
&\int_a^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}=\left.\lim_{b\to\infty}\left(-\frac1x\right)\right|_a^b=-\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac1b+\frac1a=\frac1a\end{align}$$

Thus, the second improper integral converges, whereas the first one diverges.

Comment: I was typing this...

Answer (score 5):

This is not an exact answer, but for intuitive, look at diagram near zero and infinity. (note that the integral is "area under the curve")

[image]

Comment: For "intuition", the area under $\;e^{-x^2}\;$  has also the "infinity thing" (but this time towards the horizontal axis), yet the improper integral $\;\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\;$ converges. Whenver infinity kicks in, intuition can be pretty dangerous.

Comment: @Timbuc you are completely right. the reason that i gave this answer is that: in first view for someone it may be strange that integral in *interval that is very small* is infinity and conversely. BTW if the question were mine, Id accept your answer.

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you work at the problem, you'll see that you would have to evaluate $\frac{1}{0}$. Anyway, not sure what you mean by symmetric, but think about what $$\int_0^a\frac{1}{x^2}dx$$ is actually saying. It's the area under the curve of $\frac{1}{x^2}$, and the height of the curve goes to infinity as $x \to 0$. It makes sense that you would have infinite area under a curve of infinite height.

Comment: And yet $\;\int_0^a\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}\;,\;\;a>0\;$ converges ...

Comment: I tried to word my answer so I wasn't making an absolute statement about area under curves of infinite height. Just trying to say why it shouldn't be a surprise that the area could be infinite.  But yes it is not always the case that the area will be infinite.